AG-Grid - excelStyles does not work for ISO format with milliseconds
I want to export a date in an ISO format with milliseconds included. I am using the numberFormat.format as yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ. After I export, the seconds are displayed in place of milliseconds.
Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/PjVJFURIf12zT1B7?open=app.component.ts
After Excel export:
expected:
DateISO
2009-04-20T01:02:03.03Z
Actual
DateISO
2009-04-20T01:02:03.457Z
I tried various date formats, but none of the formats work. Not sure if it's a bug in AG-Grid or I am doing something wrong
format: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'

format: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ'

format: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:sssZ'

format: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:SSSZ'


Change your number format to the following:
format: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000'

